# Amplitude amplification when an exact input state is unknown but amplitude is known

Tags: grovers-algorithm, amplitude-amplification

Let initial quantum state be $|s\rangle = a|0\rangle|d_a\rangle + b|1\rangle|d_b\rangle$. I know value of amplitude $a$, but I do not know $|d_a\rangle$ and $|d_b\rangle$. These unknown states can be entangled states of computational basis - in other words, can be arbitrary. Furthermore, the unitary that constructs $|s\rangle$ is also unknown.

In such a case, is there any known amplitude amplification method that amplifies $a$?